# using rsync within the terminal

Tags: networking, samba, backup, rsync

I am relatively new to Linux(Ubuntu 12.04) . I am researching on how to use `rsync` to backup a certain folder from my local (ubuntu) computer to my windows xp networked (shared) computer.

What I want and intend to do is use the command to copy only the files that have changed since my last `rsync` backup to the xp computer.

I know there's probably software out there that can do this but I don't like adding things (software) to my computer unless I absolutely have to.

My home network set-up is shared using samba. My home network is shared within 'WORKGROUP' settings, I have certain folders that are shared on my xp computer for this reason. I figured out how to use the rsync to only copy files (on the same computer) to another folder on the same hdd. This is what I tried within terminal,

```
rsync -av /home/danny/temp /home/danny/temp2
```

But I want to be able to have the destination (networked) folder my xp computer. Any help would be appreciated cheers.

Answer (score 1):

rsync will work from your Ubuntu  to the windows backup location . It would be simplest to mount the windows backup location on your server using smaba share

```
mount -t cifs [//your Windows's ip address/sharefolder] /path-to-the-mounting-point-on-your-ubuntu -o username=[yourwindowsusername],password=[yourwindowspassword],rw
```

followed by

```
rsync -avrP /directory-to-be-backup/ /path-to-the-mounting-point-on-your-ubuntu
```

the options are a(rchive), v(erbose), r(ecursive) and P(artial).

Comment: Thanks, when you say 'mount the windows backup location on your server' I don't have a server I have 2 desktops. ?

Comment: @maple6661 It doesn't matter i mean ur machine whatever it is

Comment: so if I just do the following on my linux computer in a terminal window it will work?

Comment: @maple6661 yes, unless there is some other issues in your systems

Comment: Can you break this down a little for me I am new...
The first part 'your server's ip' <- is that my winxp ip address. 
The 2nd part '/sharefolder' <- is this name of the path or name of the folder I have shared?
The 3rd part '/server' <- what do I put there.
The 4th part 'mountpoint' <- what do I put here
The stuff after the -o is the login information for my xp computer I am assuming. And do I just run this cmd at the terminal window? Thanks.

Comment: @maple6661 I edited the answer to clarify more

Comment: mount -t cifs [//192.xxx.x.xx/test] /home/xxxxx/temp -o username=[xxxxx],password=[xxxxxxxxxxx],rw
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on [//192.168.2.18/test],
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: This is what happens when I do this as 'su'